# I want my table to display all record if no searches were found for a movie but am unsure how to do that

Tags: asp.net

[This is my code, tell me where to change because When I do search for a movie that is in a record it displays the result, but when it isn't I only get "Movie Not Found" as in the response.write.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNys3.png)SLNkq.png

Comment: Please put your question in here along with code, not a picture link to an external hosting service.

Comment: please dont put external links

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to put question as text/code instead.

For your case, I suggest you to work with datatable instead of datareader.

== With Datatable approach ==

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Content WHERE MovieTitle=@MovieTitle) SELECT * FROM Content WHERE MovieTitle=@MovieTitle ELSE SELECT * FROM Content");

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieTitle", MovieTitle.Text);
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Result");
da.Fill(dt);
con.Close();

MovieResults.DataSource = dt;
MovieResults.DataBind();
```

Based on @Shai Cohen's comment, it would be better approach by using ExecuteDataReader if transaction is forward-only. Thanks @ShaiCohen for your comment.

== Without Datatable approach ==

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Content WHERE MovieTitle=@MovieTitle) SELECT * FROM Content WHERE MovieTitle=@MovieTitle ELSE SELECT * FROM Content");

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovieTitle", MovieTitle.Text);
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();

MovieResults.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
MovieResults.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

Enjoy Coding (;

Comment: _"I suggest you to work with datatable instead of datareader"_
Why? I don't see where this would benefit OP. Why add the extra overhead involved with the datatable?

Comment: Thanks @ShaiCohen for your comment. I have updated on the answer.